# Удаление локального репозитория в Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github

Как в AndroidStudio удалить локальный репозиторий чтобы в результате от него не осталось и следа (удалились логи всех моих комитов).
Спасибо.

Comment: а файлы должны остаться?

Comment: да. проект хочу оставить таким каким он был до добавления в репозиторий локальный.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. В Studio откройте Settings -> Version Control. Удалите запись о репозитории. Закройте Studio.
2. Удалите директорию `.git`. В ней хранится все о репозитории.
3. Запустите Studio опять.

Comment: да. спасибо. папка .git скрытая. удалил её и получил желаемый результат. А теперь снова делаю в андроид студио: **VCS | Import into Version Control | Create Git Repository**  и получаю _VCS root configuration problems_

Comment: я добавил информацию в ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое. Сработало!